# MessageHandler between components in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, components, jakarta-mail

I need to create a message between components in Spring Boot.
I created a MessageHandler component to do this and I need to use a key and to clear the output message because it has singleton scope.

I don't know if it is the best way. Any suggests?

```
@Component
public class MessageHandler {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender emailSender;

    Map<String, StringBuilder> outputMessage = new HashMap<String, StringBuilder>();

    public void addMessage(@NotNull String key, @NotNull String str) {
        if (key != null && !key.isEmpty() && str != null && !str.isEmpty()) {
            if (outputMessage.containsKey(key)) {
                outputMessage.put(key, outputMessage.get(key).append(str + "\n"));
            } else {
                outputMessage.put(key, new StringBuilder(str + "\n"));
            }
        }
    }

    public String getMessage(@NotNull String key) {
        if (key != null && !key.isEmpty())
            return outputMessage.get(key).toString();
        return "";
    }

    public void clear(@NotNull String key) {
        outputMessage.remove(key);
    }

    public void sendStringAsAttachment(String to, String subject, String text, String filename) {
        MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText(text);
            byte[] bytes = getMessage(filename).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            helper.addAttachment(filename, new ByteArrayResource(bytes));
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            logger.error("Could not send file {}", ex.getMessage());
        }
        emailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. Is the requirement to concatenate messages with the same key? You could make the code a little more readable using `Map.merge()`. Also, your code is not thread-safe, use a `ConcurrentHashMap`. Otherwise, there's nothing fundamentally wrong about your code, but it's difficult to tell for sure without knowing the exact use case

Comment: Hi, the requirement is to concatenate messages across components. I added the key to avoid accidental overwrite.